# Using regex in grep filename

Tags: bash, glob

I want to search a certain string in a number of archival log folders which reflect different servers. I use 2 different commands as of now

`-bash-4.1$ zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-22[8-9]/my_app.2021-12-28-* | grep 'abc'`

and

`-bash-4.1$ zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-23[0-3]/my_app.2021-12-28-* | grep 'abc'`

I basically want to search on server folders cmmt-54-228, cmmt-54-229 .... cmmt-54-233.

I tried combining the two commands into one but it doesn't seem to be working some mistake in using regex from my side

`-bash-4.1$ zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-22[8-9]|3[0-3]/my_app.2021-12-28-* | grep 'abc'`

Please help.

Comment: You'll likely need to escape the `|` character, or enclose the expression in quotes.

Comment: What shell are you using? That is probably not  regex, but a glob, so `|` doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: I'm using bash.

Comment: @AkG Then as I said: That’s not regex. Globs don’t have regex’s `|`, but `zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-22[8-9]/my_app.2021-12-28-* /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-23[0-3]/my_app.2021-12-28-* | …` might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is not glob. See `man 7 glob` vs `man 7 regex`.

`grep` with with regex. `grep` filters **lines** that match some regular expresion.

Shell expands words that you write. Shell replaces what you write that contains "filename expansion triggers" `*` `?` `[` and *replaces* that word with a list of words of matching filenames.

You can use *extended pattern matching* (see `man bash`), which sounds like the most natural here:

```
shopt -s extglob
echo /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-2@(2[8-9]|3[0-3])/my_app.2021-12-28-*
```

In interactive shell I would just write it twice:

```
zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-22[8-9]/my_app.2021-12-28-* /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-23[0-3]/my_app.2021-12-28-*
```

Or with *brace expansion* (see `man bash`):

```
zcat /mnt/bkp/logs/cmmt-54-2{2[8-9],3[0-3]}/my_app.2021-12-28-*
```

Braces expansion first replaces the word by two words, then filename expansion replaces them for actual filenames.

You can also `find` files with a `-regex`. For that, see `man find`. (Or output a list of filenames and pipe it to `grep` and then use `xargs` or similar to pass it to a command)